# Passing Minio S3 credential to python SDK Harness with docker mode for BEAM 2.27 + FLINK 1.10

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to setup Beam v2.27 + Flink 1.10 + Minio.  When run the wordcount example with Loopback mode.  It is working fine.

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --environment_type LOOPBACK --input s3://test/word.txt --output s3://test/out --s3_access_key_id *** --s3_secret_access_key *** --s3_endpoint_url http://10.10.10.10:9000 --runner FlinkRunner --flink_master localhost:8081
```

However, if I change to docker mode, then I get the following error.  Docker image used is apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.27.0

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --environment_type DOCKER --input s3://test/word.txt --output s3://test/out --s3_access_key_id *** --s3_secret_access_key *** --s3_endpoint_url http://10.10.10.10:9000 --runner FlinkRunner --flink_master localhost:8081
```

> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction 2: Traceback (most recent call last):'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1374, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1426, in process'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    element)'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1545, in initial_restriction'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    range_tracker = element_source.get_range_tracker(None, None)'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 210, in get_range_tracker'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    return self._get_concat_source().get_range_tracker('
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 200, in _f'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    return fnc(self, *args, **kwargs)'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 145, in _get_concat_source'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    match_result = FileSystems.match([pattern])[0]'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py", line 209, in match'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    return filesystem.match(patterns, limits)'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystem.py", line 765, in match'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'    raise BeamIOError("Match operation failed", exceptions)'
> INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:b'apache_beam.io.filesystem.BeamIOError: Match operation failed with exceptions {'s3://test/word.txt': BeamIOError("exists() operation failed with exceptions {'s3://test/word.txt': ValueError('Must provide one of client or options')}")}'

When debug python harness worker, S3 client/credential for filesystem seems initialized by pipeline option, but pipeline option for the worker in docker mode is None.  Thus the exception is raised.  Does any one have idea what might be wrong?  How can I properly pass the S3 credential to harness worker?

Much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11799. Could you please try if Beam v2.28 works.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes,  It works with v2.28.  Thanks for the pointer.  :D